# Dart lang replaceAllMapped replace function using external string variable

Tags: dart, replace

```
//1
print("abc".replaceAllMapped(RegExp("(.).+"), (m) => "${m[1]}"));
//printed "a"

//2
var r = r"${m[1]}";  //variables from outside
print("abc".replaceAllMapped(RegExp("(.).+"), (m) => r));
//printed "${m[1]}"
//How can I get the same result "a" as the first example
```

**How can I get the same result as the first example**

I'm new to Dart lang and don't know what keywords to search for this.

Thank you.

I tried this, but maybe it's not a better way?

```
  var r = r"${m[1]}";
  print("abc".replaceAllMapped(RegExp("(.).+"), (m) {
    var r2 = r;
    for (var i = 0; i <= m.groupCount; i++) {
      r2 = r2.replaceAll("\${m[$i]}", m[i]!);
    }
    return r2;
  }));
```

Comment: String interpolation is *compile-time* syntactic sugar.  There is no way to automatically transform a literal string such as `r"${m[1]}"` into `m[1]` at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to make this dynamic regex and replacement work? There is no programming language like this :(

Comment: Pretty much any *compiled* programming language will be like this.  What you essentially want to do is to execute code (access a variable named `m`) stored as a string, and doing that would require bundling a language interpreter with your program (among other things).  It's not clear what you actually want to do beyond your trivial example; there perhaps is a better way to do it.

Comment: thanks, i just want to do something like this javascript code:

var x = "$1";
console.info("abc".replace(/(.).+/g,x))

Comment: Nothing about that needs to be dynamic, so either you don't need to do it dynamically or you need to provide a better explanation or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a string. Use a function that you pass to `replaceAllMapped`.

```dart
// Replacement *function*
String r(Match m) => "${m[1]}"; // Take a `Match`, return a string.
print("abc".replaceAllMapped(RegExp("(.).+"), r));
```

If you really, really need the replacement "pattern" to come from a string (or other user input), you need to decide on a format yourself, and parse and implement that format. There is no string format provided by the platform.
The format can be as simple or complex as you want it to, since you implement it yourself.

Example:

```dart
// My replacement format: %<digits> replaces with that match.
String Function(Match) parseReplacement(String replacement) =>
    (Match match) => replacement.replaceAllMapped(
        _percentDigits, (rematch) => match[int.parse(rematch[1]!)] ?? "");

final _percentDigits = RegExp(r"%(\d+)");

/// Use as:
void main() async {
  print(
    "arglebargle".replaceAllMapped(
        RegExp(r"([aeiou])(.)"), // Wovel and next char.
        parseReplacement("%2%1")), // Swap them.
  ); // Prints "raglberagle".
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should be a function, not a string.

Comment: How to generate a dynamic function? The regular expression is dynamically generated, and the replaced parameters are also generated. Do you have any examples? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to make this dynamic regex and replacement work? There is no programming language like this :(

Comment: You cannot create a function dynamically. If you get the replacement format from user input, and don't know it at compile time, then you need to parse that format at runtime. I've given an example of that.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like there is no other way?

Comment: What would another way be? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you prefix a String with 'r', like `r"some string"`, what is created is a raw string. In a raw string, all characters are interpreted literally - that is to say, there are no escape sequences and no interpolation.

The reason you're seeing the result `"${m[1]}"` in the second example, is because that's the raw string that `r` holds.

If you want your variable `r` to hold the character `'a'`, then simply remove the 'r' from in front of the string literal, so that the value of `m[1]` will be interpolated into the string.

```
var r = "${m[1]}";

// Or better yet (since string interpolation is not necessary here):
var r = m[1];
```

Comment: Thank you, But the external m variable has not been defined at this time, so it can't find it and report an error?